# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN

Tags: ios, uibutton

When I'm clicking button I'm getting this exception.I don't know where I'm doing wrong Someone help me .my app is rejected because of this exception
my code:

```
 UILabel *rememberMeLabelObj = [[UILabel  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xaxisForRememberMeLabel, yaxisForRememberMeLabel, widthForRememberMeLabel, heightForRememberMeLabel)];
rememberMeLabelObj.text = @"Remember me";
rememberMeLabelObj.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

rememberMeLabelObj.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.816f green:0.592f  blue:0.157f alpha:1.00f];
[self.view addSubview:rememberMeLabelObj];
```

Comment: once refer these links they may help you   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864096/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-cal                             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867968/calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-0-0-nan-nan-cr

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Nandu .i'll go through those links

Comment: thank you @Nandu I didn't gave .0f to the values .now it's working fine .your links helped me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN: \[0 0; nan nan\] crash in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867968/calayerinvalidgeometry-reason-calayer-bounds-contains-nan-0-0-nan-nan-cr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my issue actually I didn't gave float values because of this I got exception.I gave CGFloat and gave values as integer like 400,350,etc but I need give 400.0f .so,I got this issue .Now it was cleared

Comment: Strange!! This can lead to crash never thought of it.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling UILabel frame methods, and probably calculating the value somehow and the result is a NaN, which means "not a number" and, as you correctly suggested, it can be the result of o divide-by-zero operation.

But it can appear for a lot other reasons: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Reference: [kuba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025547/3859370)

Comment: thank you @Naeem I'm searching lot of links for this exception .I'll refer which you have suggested

Comment: @Naeem I am setting my label's width = 0. It may cause issue? My code is something like `CGRect r = self.lblProgress.frame;
    r.size.width = 0;
    self.lblProgress.frame = r;`

Answer (score 1):

My iOS App has the same problem when the simulator version is 8.x, it is no problem in version 9.x,after I have checked and removed the following code, the problem is solved!

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
  [LoadTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

  [super viewWillAppear:YES];

 }


 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [LoadTableView reloadData];

   LoadTableView.hidden = 0;

   [super viewDidAppear:YES];


 }
```

Comment: setting a BOOL to "0" should work, how ever I would recommend you use YES or NO